# How to create a fixed div when somebody scroll our page like facebook ads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I see that when we scroll down Facebook window, the ads divs are fixed right after it reach bottom of the ads.
How to do that?

I think we can do it by using JavaScript and CSS, does somebody know the code for it?

Comment: http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/make-a-div-stick-to-top-when-scrolled-to/#axzz2oxN0uwpQ

Comment: yes you can use css property position: fixed;

Comment: Are you looking for [Sticky Sidebar](http://web3canvas.com/item/jquery-sticky-for-long-sidebar/) ?

Comment: @SurjithSM i don't know what we call it, but i think sticky sidebar is what i want,, , thanks http://demo.web3canvas.com/jquery/jquery-sticky-for-long-sidebar/

Answer (score 0):

A 
`position:fixed`

in your css including the class or the id you are using will help you do as you are wishing.